# UITabBar disappears when selecting UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbar

I have a UITableView with a cell named 'Sunset'. Upon pressing the UITableViewCell, the view switches to 'infoView' which loads some text from a .txt file. When pressing the 'back' button, the view switches back to the UITableView but there's a problem. After loading the view, the UITabBar is gone! Since it is gone, it is impossible to go back to another view.

I have tried:

```
self.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = NO;
```

Code:

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
    UITableViewCell *cellSelected = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSString *cellTitle = cellSelected.textLabel.text;

    if (cellTitle == @"Sunrise")
    { //Swap views
        informationView *iv = [[informationView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
        [self presentModalViewController:iv animated:YES]; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us see the code in didSelectRowAtIndexPath and where you create your tableView

Comment: Always edit your original question to add the code, not add a comment with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course the tab bar doesn't show. You are presenting the second view modally. If you want to keep this implementation you are going to have to add a button or something on the second view that will perform

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];  //Programatically dismiss the view controller
```

If you want to keep the tabBar and the navigation bar functionality, you should use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:iv animated:YES];
```

instead of

```
[self presentModalViewController:iv animated:YES];
```